# Problem after publishing RMarkdown document, including headers wirth "Umlauts"

Tags: r, r-markdown, bookdown

After successfully building to **bookdown::gitbook** my rmarkdown project, I am publishing it to rstudio pubs. The problem lies, when I am trying to open one of the subchapters, which includes in the header an "Umlaut" character. I am really struggling to overcome this problem. Any suggestion would be highly appreciated.
Attached you can find some relevant screenshots, where the problem is depicted.
Thanks in advance for your time!

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: can you give a mwe. As far as I can guess it may be caused by the Umlaut being used in the url. what system are u on?

Comment: somehow I can't reproduce the error I'm on macos and using yihui mwe with an umlaut in chapter title

Comment: @AbdessabourMtk First of all thanks a lot for your answer. I am using windows 10 and still I cannot solve the problem. I created also a custom url in rstudio pubs, but the problem remains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After all this time I found the solution to the problem I posted. Basically I decided to publish/host the rendered output of mine on GitHub pages. On GitHub pages there was no error caused by the presence of `Umlauts` on any of my headers.